# How to disable EEE in TG3 Driver (disable energy efficiency ethernet)?

Tags: networking, power-management

I can easily set the eee to off (0) by using ethtools, but it doesn't stay disabled after a reboot - how do I make it permanent? Do I have to rebuild the driver with the EEE flag?

Comment: Worst case scenario you could add the `ethtool` command you use to disable eee on your `/etc/rc.local`

Answer (score 0):

I was able to toggle EEE by enabling/disabling pcie power saving features in the BIOS.